# GDB: How to watch an address whenever new value is assigned to?

Tags: gdb, watch

I use "watch" command of gdb to track the value of one address. However, gdb only stops when the value is changed to a different one. So how to stop the process whenever the value of the address is assigned a new value, so condition that the same value is assigned will also stops the process.

Comment: watch - only breaks on write (and only if the value changes)

Answer (score 1):

> So how to stop the process whenever the value of the address is assigned a new value
>   ... (which could be the same as old value).

There is currently no way to do that in GDB.

Although it's not hard to implement this in GDB, the need to do this is rare (the program state is *not* changed, so why do you care that the same value is written to memory as it was before?).

You can use `rwatch` to break whenever the value is read. That will give you a superset of your desired break locations, though if the variable is read a lot, and written rarely, `rwatch` may not be a good solution.

Comment: What a pity~   I want to know which branch is really executed to write the address.

Comment: @river Can you expand your question to explain your use case a bit? E.g. why is setting breakpoint on file/line is not sufficient?

Comment: I came here because I have a black box observable with a remote debugger and I am experimenting with using a write watch on a well defined location to observe current "context". If this "context" is the same as before, the trick fails to kick in.